# Modifying a statsmodels graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, statsmodels, vector-auto-regression

I am following the statsmodels documentation here:
https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/vector_ar.html

I get to the part at the middle of the page that says:
`irf.plot(orth=False)`

which produces the following graph for my data:
[image]

I need to modify the elements of the graph. E.g., I need to apply tight_layout and also decrease the y-tick sizes so that they don't get into the graphs to their left.

The documentation talks about passing "subplot plotting funcions" in to the `subplot` argument of irf.plot(). But when I try something like:

```
irf.plot(subplot_params = {'fontsize': 8, 'figsize' : (100, 100), 'tight_layout': True})
```

only the `fontsize` parameter works. I also tried passing these parameters to the 'plot_params' argument but of no avail.

So, my question is how can I access other parameters of this irf.plot, especially the figsize and ytick sizes? I also need to force it to print a grid, as well as all values on the x axis (1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 10)

Is there any way I can create a blank plot using the `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` way and then create the irf.plot on that figure?

Comment: figsize and tight_layout are options for the figure as shown in the answer, not options for subplots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the function returns a [matplotlib.figure](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html):

Try doing this:

```
fig = irf.plot(orth=False,..)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.set_figheight(100)
fig.set_figwidth(100)
```

If I run it with this example, it works:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.api import VAR

mdata = sm.datasets.macrodata.load_pandas().data
dates = mdata[['year', 'quarter']].astype(int).astype(str)
quarterly = dates["year"] + "Q" + dates["quarter"]
from statsmodels.tsa.base.datetools import dates_from_str
quarterly = dates_from_str(quarterly)
mdata = mdata[['realgdp','realcons','realinv']]
mdata.index = pandas.DatetimeIndex(quarterly)
data = np.log(mdata).diff().dropna()
model = VAR(data)

results = model.fit(maxlags=15, ic='aic')
irf = results.irf(10)

fig = irf.plot(orth=False)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.set_figheight(30)
fig.set_figwidth(30)
```

[image]